# How to to run spark cluster on ec2 from sbt?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sbt, apache-spark

I have a program written in scala, using spark, which runs fine locally when I start it with `sbt run`

I would like to be able to run it on amazon's ec2 clusters using sbt. 
Is that possible and how?

I've looked at http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html, but that seems to do things without sbt.

My sbt version:

```
~/git-reps/cs262a $ sbt --version
sbt launcher version 0.12.4
```

My `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "Ensemble Bayes Tree"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "0.8.0-incubating",
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.9.3" % "0.8.0-incubating",
 "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.6.4",
 "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.5",
 "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.14",
 "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "2.5.0.v201103041518" artifacts Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")
)

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After launching an EC2 cluster, you can copy your code to the cluster's master node, log into the master using ssh, and run sbt on that machine (the [AMP Camp 3 exercises](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/3/exercises/logging-into-the-cluster.html) work this way, for example).

Make sure to pass the Spark master's address when creating SparkContext in your driver program.  I'd `source /root/spark/conf/spark-env.sh` to set the `$MASTER` environment variable then read that variable in my driver program.  The master's address is also stored in `/root/spark-ec2/cluster-url`.

Sourcing `spark-env.sh` will also set a few environment variables for configuring your Spark's job's memory usage based on the size of the cluster's nodes.  If you don't source this file, make sure to set the `spark.executor.memory` Java system property in your driver in order to make full use of the cluster's memory.

Comment: Thanks for clearing out the approach. 
That ampCamp web page seems like a solid resource!